# Vector-Tensor element-wise multiplication in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to extract the luminance from a tensor representing an image in Pytorch, and so I need to multiply element-wise a vector of size 3 (for the three RGB value weights) by a 3xNxN tensor representing the image such that I obtain a NxN matrix in the end where the three channels of the tensor have been summed with the weights given in the vector.

I guess there exists Pytorch operations that would help me do that without loops but I haven't found them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reshape your `3` dimensional RGB vector to be broadcastable to `3xNxN` like this:

```
rgb = rgb.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

So it will have shape `(3, 1, 1)`

Now you can multiply it with original image and sum along first dimension:

```
result = torch.sum(rgb * image, dim=0)
```

Comment: @user13459183 mark as an answer with green ticket if your issue is your solved, thanks